# Custom Post Title as search term

Tags: posts, search, title, customization

is there any way to include custom post title as search term. I create custom post types - VHS, DVD, Blu Ray. Then in search box when I write DVD I want to list all posts from custom post type DVD.

Thank you all in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you [register the post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) with `public` set to `true`, the titles will be included automatically. You shouldn't have to do anything to make this happen. Something as simple as this [from the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type):

```
function codex_custom_init() {
    $args = array( 'public' => true, 'label' => 'Books' );
    register_post_type( 'book', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'codex_custom_init' );
```

If you aren't sure you can test it with this:

```
function test_custom_types_inclusion($where) {
  if (is_search()) {
    wp_die(var_dump($where));
  }
}
add_filter('posts_where','test_custom_types_inclusion');
```

That will completely break you search but you can see the raw `WHERE` clause to confirm that your CPT is included. Look for the `post_type IN (` part.

That covers this question:

> is there any way to include custom post title as search term[?]

But I think you meant that you want to search the names you use to register the types, not the titles. To include all posts listed in a custom post type-- and I don't see the logic of doing that, as you are going to get a potentially huge number of results, making the search more or less useless-- something like this...

```
function custom_types_inclusion_wpse_81742($where) {
  if (is_search()) {
    global $wpdb;
    $where .= " OR {$wpdb->posts}.post_type = 'your-type-name'";
  }
  return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where','custom_types_inclusion_wpse_81742');
```

But to have your search terms respected you will have to get more complicated.

```
function custom_types_inclusion_wpse_81742_v2($search) {
  global $wpdb;
  $terms = preg_match_all('/%([^%]+)%/',$search,$matches);
  $ts = array();
  if (!empty($matches[1])) {
    $matches = array_unique($matches[1]);
    if (!empty($matches)) {
      foreach ($matches as $m) {
        $ts[] = "{$wpdb->posts}.post_type LIKE '%{$m}%'";
      }
    }
    if (!empty($ts)) {
      $search .= "OR ((".implode(') OR (',$ts).'))';
    }
  }
  return $search;
}
add_filter('posts_search','custom_types_inclusion_wpse_81742');
```

Untested but I think that  should do it.

Again, I don't see the logic. Results aren't going to mean much.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. It works, but I have one question. Your example work only with one post type - OR {$wpdb->posts}.post_type = 'your-type-name' How to make it check more than one custom post type?

Comment: Add more `OR` conditions or use `IN` the way WordPress does for `post_type`

Comment: I try with this code:

`{$wpdb->posts}.post_type IN ( 'vhs', 'dvd' )`

But now when I write in search box - DVD it shows all post from both post types VHS and DVD.

Comment: Added a new version.

Comment: Many thanks for the new code, but I don't understand, where can I define which custom post titles can be used as search terms?
 
One friend has site, with many custom post types. Many of the  new users don't use navigation (mainly because it's huge), but use search instead and they often use custom post titles as search terms. That's why we want to add this functionality.

Comment: The new code should use the existing search terms-- the stuff sent by `?s=` queries if you aren't using pretty permalinks.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I have one last question. In search results sidebar I have list with last added articles. After I put your code, the list shows search results articles and then last added artices. Can I fix this?

Comment: I don't know how your sidebar works.

Comment: I update my first post with code of the widget with articles in sidebar.